# How to delete smallest file if names are duplicate

Tags: linux, shell, batch-delete

I would like to clean up a folder with videos. I have a bunch of videos that were downloaded with different resolutions, so each file will start with the same name and then end with "_480p" or "_720p" etc.

I just want to keep the largest file of each such set.

So I am looking for a way to delete files based on

1. check if name before "_" is identical
2. if true, then delete all files except largest one

Comment: So, you have 2 resolutions for each video, 480 and 720 for each file? If so, you can do `rm *_480p` and it will delete all files with that name ending.

Comment: @MrFrenzoid: which is wrong, because it will delete also the videos that were 480p *only* and cause data loss.

Comment: True, i thought they had and HD version of each file :)

Answer (score 1):

Thinking of a flexible and fast way to approach the problem, you can gather a list of files ending in `"[[:digit:]]+p"` and then a quick way to parse the names is to provide them on `stdin` to `awk` and let `awk` index an array with the file prefix (path + part of name before `'_'`) so it will be unique for files allowing the different format size to be obtained and stored at that index.

Then it's a simply matter of comparing the stored resolution number for the file against the current file number and deleting the lesser of the two.

Your find command to locate all files in the directory below the current, recursively, could be:

```sh
find ./tmp -type f -regex "^.*[0-9]+p$"
```

What I would do is then pipe the filename output to a short `awk` script where an array stores the last seen number for a given file prefix, and then if the current record (line) resolution number if bigger than the value stored in the array, a filename using the array number is created and that file deleted with `system()` using `rm filename`. If the current line resolution number is less than what is already stored in the array for the file, you simply delete the current file.

You can do that as:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS = "/" }
{
  num = $NF        # last field holds number up to 'p'
  prefix = $0      # prefix is name up to "_[[:digit:]]+p
  
  sub (/^.*_/, "", num)                 # isolate number
  sub (/p$/, "", num)                   # remove 'p' at and
  sub (/_[[:digit:]]+p$/, "", prefix)   # isolate path and name prefix
  
  if (prefix in a) {                    # current file in array a[] ?
    rmfile = $0                         # set file to remove to current
    if (num + 0 > a[prefix] + 0) {      # current number > array number
      rmfile = prefix "_" a[prefix] "p" # for remove filename from array
      a[prefix] = num                   # update array with higher num
    }
    system ("rm " rmfile);              # delete the file 
  }
  else
    a[prefix] = num     # if no num for prefix in array, store first
}
```

(**note:** the field-separator splits the fields using the directory separator so you have all file components to work with.)

**Example Use/Output**

With a representative set of files in a `tmp/` directory below the current, e,g.

```
$ ls -1 tmp
a_480p
a_720p
b_1080p
b_480p
c_1080p
c_720p
```

Running the `find` command piped to the awk script named `awkparse.sh` would be as follows (don't forget to make the awk script executable):

```
$ find ./tmp -type f -regex "^.*[0-9]+p$" | ./awkparse.sh
```

Looking at the directory after piping the results of `find` to the `awk` script, the `tmp/` directory now only contains the highest resolution (largest) files for any given filename, e.g.

```
$ ls -1
a_720p
b_1080p
c_1080p
```

This would be highly efficient. It could also handle all files in a nested directory structure where multiple directory levels hold files you need to clean out. Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thank you sir, this was about the shortest way I could see doing it -- I'm sure Ed might cut that in half `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I would try to:

- list all non-smallest files (non-480p): `*_720p*` and `*_1080p*`
- for each of them replace `*_720p*`/`*_1080p*` in the name with all possible smaller resolutions
- and try to delete those files with `rm -f`, whether they exist or not

```sh
#!/bin/sh -e
shopt -s nullglob

for file in *_1080p*; do
    rm -f -- "${file//_1080p/_720p}"
    rm -f -- "${file//_1080p/_480p}"
done

for file in *_720p*; do
    rm -f -- "${file//_720p/_480p}"
done
```

And here is a Bash script using nested loops to automate the above:

```sh
#!/bin/bash -e
shopt -s nullglob

res=(_1080p _720p _480p _240p)

for r in ${res[@]}; do
    res=("${res[@]:1}") # remove the first element in res array
    for file in *$r*; do
        for r2 in ${res[@]}; do
            rm -f -- "${file//$r/$r2}"
        done
    done
done
```

Comment: Some videos only have 240p. Some have 5-8 different resolution (or resolution plus forced subtitles). So the search really needs to be as stated above.

Comment: Then you need to add 240p in the 2 loops above, and also do a 3rd loop for 480p removing 240p.

Comment: You could add another nested loop to avoid duplicating code, but I think the example might get less readable.

Comment: `[linux]` and `[shell]` mean POSIX shell (not an advanced shell like `[bash]` or `[zsh]`) POSIX shell does not have arrays. In these cases it is worth clarifying by comment what shell is being used or if their intent is to be portable.

Answer (score 0):

This shell script might be what you want:

```
previous_prefix=

for file in *_[0-9]*[0-9]p*; do
    prefix=${file%_*}
    resolution=${file##*_}
    resolution=${resolution%%p*}
    if [ "$prefix" = "$previous_prefix" ]; then
        if [ "$resolution" -gt "$greater_resolution" ]; then
            file_to_be_removed=$greater_file
            greater_file=$file
            greater_resolution=$resolution
        else
            file_to_be_removed=$file
        fi
        echo rm -- "$file_to_be_removed"
    else
        greater_resolution=$resolution
        greater_file=$file
        previous_prefix=$prefix
    fi
done
```

Drop the `echo` if the output looks good.

Comment: You could actually move the files to a folder in /tmp or something.